# I'm trying to copy a file from public s3 bucket and put it into my dynamodb databse. What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm a beginner in nodejs.

How can I copy data from s3 to dynamodb using node js? I have a json file in s3 that I want to copy

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: '********',
secretAccessKey: '**********',
region: '*****',
endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
})


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        console.log(event);
        //get the file name
        let key = event['filename.json'];
        let getObject = {Bucket: 'Bucket-name', Key: `${key}`};
        //get the object
        let response = await s3.getObject(getObject).promise();
```

this code below works fine when I use actual file name that is in my local machine in place of response

```
        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

        console.log("Importing movies into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

        var allMovies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('response', 'utf8'));
        allMovies.forEach(function(movie) {
            var params = {
                TableName: "Movies",
                Item: {
                    "year":  movie.year,
                    "title": movie.title,
                    "info":  movie.info
                }
            };

            docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
               if (err) {
                   console.error("Unable to add movie", movie.title, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
               } else {
                   console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.title);
               }
            });
        });




    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        return error;
    }
};
```

Comment: Jitish, you've asked two questions on Stack Overflow. Both have been answered. You've deleted one question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663267) entirely, even though the answer appears to have been correct and helpful, and you've failed to respond in any way to the answer on the 2nd question (this question). This is not the best way to respect people's time on Stack Overflow or to contribute to the overall value of the site. Please reconsider how you interact going forward, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, you were really helpful. I'm new here I'm learning I'll take care next time

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

1. Credentials in the Lambda Code - **don't do this**, that's what IAM Roles are for.
2. Your S3 download doesn't do what you think it does, it doesn't download a file on the filesystem but returns an object you process further.
3. You try to read from a file called `response` which most likely doesn't exist - see 2

I'm not a JS guy myself, so I just googled a little and found this code [here](https://www.mydatahack.com/uploading-and-downloading-files-in-s3-with-node-js/):

```
const downloadFile = (filePath, bucketName, key) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key
  };
  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data.Body.toString());
    console.log(`${filePath} has been created!`);
  });
};
```

You can use that function synchronously to download the file to a path unter `/tmp` and then read it from there.

```
downloadFile(filePath, bucketName, key);
```

**PLEASE DO NOT STORE AWS CREDENTIALS IN YOUR CODE UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES**